# How can I get_posts with pages using several page templates?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `get_posts()` to return an array of pages all using a specific page template, but can I adjust so this it also pulls in pages using another (or several) page templates?

```
$procedure_pages = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php'
        )
    )
));
```

Can I simple turn `value` into a nested array like this?

```
$procedure_pages = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => array(
                'template-procedure.php',
                'template-procedure-minimal.php'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: TUrns out I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to look for it in an array of templates

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => array ( 'template-procedure.php', 'template-procedure-minimal.php' ),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: As thought in my question, even `compare` isn't needed, but thanks for the answer!